# GPU not available according to TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm currently trying to run Keras with TensorFlow backend on my GPU and tried to check whether my GPU is available with the following code:

```
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
```

However, this returns 0

Using the following code:

```
device_lib.list_local_devices()
```

returns:

```
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
 device_type: "CPU"
 memory_limit: 268435456
 locality {
 }
 incarnation: 16955368014442285079,
 name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
 device_type: "XLA_CPU"
 memory_limit: 17179869184
 locality {
 }
 incarnation: 12826643223491695600
 physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device",
 name: "/device:XLA_GPU:0"
 device_type: "XLA_GPU"
 memory_limit: 17179869184
 locality {
 }
 incarnation: 11161186744787304312
 physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"]
```

It seems like the GPU is recognized but not seen as available, does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Pytorch.

Since you have an identified GPU, I suggest you to check your driver version and make sure your tensorflow version is compatible with this version.

Comment: How do you suggest I handle this problem, I don't know which versions are meant to be compatible